# Can't get Netbeans Project to acknowledge existing Tomcat or Glassfish Server

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, gradle, netbeans, configuration

I haven't been able to figure out what I'm missing here.

I've installed Tomcat and can spin it up fine. (Glassfish too, in my efforts, but I had removed it when I took the screenshot.)

[image: Screenshot of Tomcat Server showing in Services]

So now I want to hook my project up to the Tomcat instance so I can have Netbeans deploy it for me automatically.

I right-click on my project, go down to Properties. In Project Properties I select 'Run' and go to the drop down to select my server. Only, there's no servers.

[image: No servers options showing up for my Project]

Why is it not showing up here? Am I going about this all wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Other potentially useful notes:
* Using Gradle (for my first time)
* Using Spring Boot (for my first time)
* On Windows 10 (don't hate me, I don't love it either)

Comment: More information is needed: [1] To determine if this is a general problem, or specific to that project, create a trivial new Gradle web project (**File > New Project... > Java with Gradle > Web Application**). When the Wizard invites you to select a server, is Tomcat offered as an option, and can you successfully build, deploy and run that new project? [2] What is shown in your broken project's properties for **Build > Compile > Java Platform**?

Comment: Thank you @skomisa.

Question 1a: When the wizard invites me to select a server, Tomcat *is* offered as an option.

Relevant Info: I did *not* use the wizard to create the project in question. I used start.spring.io to give me a ZIP, then used File > Import Project > From Zip.

1b: It did successfully build and run, and claimed to deploy successfully as well, however my tomcat manager shows no such application deployed. I also received a message saying after starting: "Undeployed the application at context path [/]"

Question 2: Build > Compile > Java Platform is JDK 1.8 (Default)

Comment: Okay, new information, narrowing it down. I created a new gradle project, selected my Tomcat. Once created I copied my build spring-boot-version of my build.gradle file into the new project, overwriting the default one. I then checked the Project Properties again and suddenly, no more server. So, the culprit appears to be the gradle file I got from spring.start.io (not blaming them for an error, just recognizing my next step). So next I need to figure out what that's doing and why it's affecting my server. Most of it, btw, is in the screenshot above.

Comment: There appear to be two changes I can make to the build.gradle file, either of which cause the issue with the server not showing up in the Project Properties > Run section.

1) If I comment out this dependency that came in the default build.gradle file when netbeans created the project: providedCompile 'javax:javaee-web-api:7.0'
Even adding all the other dependencies from the spring-boot build.gradle file, the server could be selected until I commented out this line.
2) By changing the repositories from jcenter() (the one netbeans provided) to mavenCentral() (the one spring-boot provided).

Comment: OK. [1] It's worth creating another (trivial) Spring Boot project externally and importing/running it within NetBeans to see whether the issue is reproducible. Does that work? [2] If it does the problem is obviously specific to your broken project, but if not it is probably an issue related to importing Spring Boot Gradle projects into NetBeans. To get help on that you would need to update your question with details on how you originally created the project, and how it was imported into NetBeans. You need to provide sufficient detail so that others can attempt to reproduce your problem.

Comment: (Mostly) ignore my previous post - I have just seen your most recent comments. The simplest immediate fix would then be to add `providedCompile 'javax:javaee-web-api:7.0'` into **build.gradle** for your broken project, right?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Even with that dependency added, having the repository be mavenCentral() instead of jcenter() still causes the issue. If I use jcenter() instead of mavenCentral(), I get compiler issues.

I haven't figured it out yet, but my gut feel is that the config is trying to somehow override the external tomcat server... but I have nothing to back that up.

Comment: Ok, resolved. Kinda mostly. In my dependencies was this: providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat' . It seems Spring Boot provides its own internal tomcat server. ...somewhere. No idea, but they do. Going back to the pure spring-boot framework and running it, the actual error I was getting was with :bootRun and said "a problem occurred starting process" and then a path to my java.exe. Found a link elsewhere that said to run `./gradlew clean build` and then `java -jar build/libs/bookstore-0.0.1.SNAPSHOT.war`. That led me to errors about not having a db configured...

Comment: ...so I commented out all the dependencies in my build.gradle that had to do with db stuff (that I don't have set up, but anticipate wanting), and then it worked. Oh, I also removed my external Tomcat install from the Servers in netbeans. But I can use postman and hit my REST controller and it all works out! Onto the next step. Thanks @skomisa for your comments!

Comment: Ah, good call. Thanks @skomisa!

Answer (score 1):

I was chasing the wrong problem. Spring-boot provides an embedded server so I had no need to install and provide my own.

My real problem was that I had dependencies declared for jpa, postgresql, etc. that I hadn't configured in application.properties. When I tried to run, I'd get an error saying "a problem occurred starting process /path/to/my/jdk/java.exe". I couldn't figure what was going on and, looking around, I saw the issue mentioned in my question about the server.

The solution was to simply comment out the dependencies in my build.gradle until I was ready for them. After I got my PostgreSQL DB set up and added the configureation to application.properties, I was able to un-comment them and it's working great.